Is the homotopy limit of connected spaces connected?
I am working with homotopy limits of mapping spaces (in simplicial sets or topological spaces), and if perchance path connectedness was preserved by homotopy limits, I would be very happy.
However a priori I don't believe this dream of mine, as for ordinary limits, this is false. Take the equalizer of the constant map equal to $1$ and of the squaring map $x^2, 1\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.
However, it could be that adding the adjective "homotopy" makes things nicer since connectedness is a homotopy invariant property; this doesn't seem absurd. However, for me these objects are (in general) too mysterious to come up with a proof or a counterexample.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

The homotopy pullback of $1 \to S^1 \leftarrow 1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$.

The obstruction for this to happen is essentially a $\lim^1$ term by Milnor's exact sequence. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lim%5E1+and+Milnor+sequences

@QiZhu Oh thanks, this might actually be enough in my specific case (at the very least it is enough to say something interesting)

This is generally false, and your example that this fails for ordinary limits is not so hard to translate into a counterexample for homotopy limits: Consider the map $\phi\colon S^1 \to S^1$, $z \mapsto z^2$ and let $F$ be its homotopy fibre (i.e. the homotopy equalizer between it and some choice of constant map $S^1 \to S^1$). We then get a long exact sequence on homotopy groups
$$
    0 \to \pi_1 F \to \underbrace{\pi_1 X}_{\cong \mathbb{Z}} \overset{\cdot 2}{\to} \underbrace{\pi_1 Y}_{\cong \mathbb{Z}} \to \pi_0 F \to 0
$$
so $\pi_1 F = 0$ and $\pi_0 F \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, whence $F$ is not path-connected (in fact, $\phi$ is a covering map with fibre of cardinality two, so it already models $F$).

Thanks for the counterexample!
